# looping through multiple files with bash command

Tags: shell-script, for

I have a file with listed sample names

```
head sample_id.txt
PD26405a--PD26405b
PD26414a--PD26414d
PD26417a--PD26417b
...
```

I also have a directory with the outputs of preprocessing step of the program that I am running

```
cd ./preprocessing_out
ls
PD26405a--PD26405b_allDirichletProcessInfo.txt
PD26405a--PD26405b_alleleFrequencies.txt
PD26405a--PD26405b_loci.txt
PD26405a--PD26405b_master.txt
PD26414a--PD26414d_allDirichletProcessInfo.txt
PD26414a--PD26414d_alleleFrequencies.txt
PD26414a--PD26414d_loci.txt
PD26414a--PD26414d_master.txt
PD26417a--PD26417b_allDirichletProcessInfo.txt
PD26417a--PD26417b_alleleFrequencies.txt
PD26417a--PD26417b_loci.txt
PD26417a--PD26417b_master.txt
```

sample names in sample_id.txt file matched with file names in preprocessing_out directory.

I want to run my main step script which takes only *_master.txt file.
master file looks like this:

```
cat PD26405a--PD26405b_master.txt
sample  subsample   datafile    cellularity sex cnadatafile indeldatafiles
PD26405a--PD26405b  PD26405a--PD26405b  PD26405a--PD26405b_allDirichletProcessInfo.txt  0.83    female  NA  NA
```

If I want to run it for the first sample only

it is simply

```
Rscript --vanilla --slave /projects/dpclust_pipeline.R  -r 1 -d /projects/preprocessing_out -o /projectsdp_out -i /projects/preprocessing_out/PD26405a--PD26405b_master.txt


--r is ("run_sample"), type="integer", default=NULL, help="Sample to run".
--d is the directory that preprocessing results stored
--o is the directory that final output directory
--I is the path to master.txt
```

I have more than 150 samples in total and I want to run this Rscript in a bash script with for loop. r=1 refers to first sample (PD26405a--PD26405b), r =2 refers to (PD26414a--PD26414d), and so on.

How can I adjust my code?

Answer (score 0):

To just count up with r as you get another file, you can do something like:

```
r=1
while read sample
do
  Rscript --vanilla --slave /projects/dpclust_pipeline.R  -r ${r} -d /projects/preprocessing_out -o /projectsdp_out -i /projects/preprocessing_out/${sample}_master.txt
  r=$(( r + 1 ))
done < path/to/sample_id.txt
```

Comment: thanks, but where should I put my Rscript command?

Comment: You can replace the echo command above.  I wanted you to try running with echo first to test/see how it works for you.  Then you can replace that line using the same variables how you want $masterfile and $r

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work the way I want

Comment: What output do you get when you run it?

Comment: r= 1 should be PD26405a--PD26405b_master.txt , r=2 should be PD26414a--PD26414d_master.txt. based on the order of samples in sample.id.txt

Comment: Ok that's not a nested loop then.  How do you know which number should go with which file?  That information would need to be provided somehow.  Or does it matter which r is assigned to which file?

Comment: /PD26405a--PD26405b_master.txt 1
/PD26405a--PD26405b_master.txt 2
/PD26405a--PD26405b_master.txt 3
....
/PD26405a--PD26405b_master.txt 10
/PD26414a--PD26414d_master.txt 1
/PD26414a--PD26414d_master.txt 2
...
/PD26414a--PD26414d_master.txt 10

Comment: it runs it 10 time for each file

Comment: I changed the title of my question, maybe this is better

Comment: The original response (first loop) gives you 10 r numbers for each file.

Comment: yes, your second answer seems to work

Comment: it did not work when I adjusted my script command to it though

Comment: Thank you for your answers, but I think you probably did not understand my question.

Comment: Indeed, sorry about that.

Comment: I want to loop through each master file but, the Rscript is designed to take r= 1,2,3,...(integers)  instead of sample name.So I need to let her know when r =1, it should take first sample PD26405a--PD26405b and master file matches to it PD26405a--PD26405b_master.txt

Comment: If they're in order, i.e. the first line in sample_id.txt corresponds to r=1 then you can use the third loop to associate the sample name with the r # (e.g. you can reference ${sample}_master.txt)

If they're not in order, you will need to create a file that associates the r# to the sample name.

Comment: Yes, the third loop works with echo command but when I try my script command with it it does not work

Comment: r=1
for masterfile in `ls /projects/*_master.txt`;
do  Rscript --vanilla --slave /projects/dpclust_pipeline.R  -r $r /projects/preprocessing_out -o /projects/dp_out -i $masterfile

  r=$(( r + 1 ))
done